# Get onEdit to trigger from a single cell change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to run a Google App script that unhides columns, and then rehides columns based whether the cell reference says Blank or not. This is determined by a drop down in a single cell. I got the script to run fine (if a little clunky) whenever any edit is made, but when I try to add the specification of cell it flags an error with the range.

I'm very new to this so I'm a bit out of my depth so any help is appreciated!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B2') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Group M0 loot");
    sheet.showColumns(9, 35);
    var range = sheet.getRange("4:4");
    var num_cols = range.getNumColumns();
    for (var i = 9; i <= num_cols; i++) {
      var value = sheet.getRange(4,i).getValue();
      if (value == "Blank") {
        sheet.hideColumns(i);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please briefly describe your spreadsheet, add the textual error message, indicate which cell has the data validation with the dropdown and clarify what you mean by  "I try to add the specification of cell it flags"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Group M0 loot" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    sh.showColumns(9, 35);
    sh.getRange(4,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().forEach((c,i) => {
      if(!c) {
        sh.hideColumns(i + 1);
      }
    });
  }
}
```